# Prove that there are infinitely many natural numbers that are not powers of any prime.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory

I am wondering whether there is a way to prove that **the set consisting of all natural numbers that are not powers of any prime is infinite**. For example, 6 is such a natural number. Just to make this clear, what I mean is that any numbers that are powers of 2,3,5,7... (prime numbers) are not in the defined set. So 2,4,8 ; 3,9,27 are not in the set.

For a set to be infinite, I mean the following:
[image]

I am trying to this by proving that this set is equivalent to $ \Bbb N$ but it is really hard to find an explicit bijection. Another way to do this is that I can prove **the set consisting of all natural numbers that are powers of a primes is countably infinite**. But it seems that the complement of a countably infinite set in $ \Bbb N$ may not be countably infinite?

Can someone please give me a hand? Thanks.

Comment: $p q$, for $p$ and $q$ distinct primes?

Comment: If $n$ is odd, $n >1$, can $2n$ be a power of a prime?

Comment: What do you mean by giving a hand???

Comment: @Sagar Mishra: The phrase "give me a hand" is an idiom. It means "help me" (e.g., "help me up").

Comment: Oh thanks for this. Actually I'm weak in idioms and all

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I have edited the question. It should be clear now.

Comment: Could you **stop** tagging everything with [set-theory] when it clearly does not fit the tag?

Comment: `p*(p+1)` for any prime?

Comment: you can construct infinitely many, which are easily mapable to the natural numbers eg 2*3->1, 2*2*3*3 ->2 etc.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What about the set $\{6^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$? This set doesn't contain any element which is a power of a prime, and it's easy to make a bijection from this set to $\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}$$\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}$Is there any reason why you would want an *explicit* bijection?

Because you can prove that your set 
$$
X = \Set{ x \in \N : \text{$x$ is not a power of a prime}}
$$ 
is in a bijection with the natural numbers without making the bijection explicit.

First note that
$$
n \mapsto 2 \cdot (2 n + 3)
$$
is an *injective* map from $\N$ to your set $X$. (I have taken $2 n + 3$ so that it works whether one includes zero in $\N$ ot not.)

Then $x \mapsto x$ is an injective map $X \mapsto \N$.

This [guarantees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem) that there is a bijection $\N \to X$.

Comment: Aha! Very smart answer. Thanks so much. I get it.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, you can get $6^1$, $6^2$, etc. Thus you can set up a one-to-one correspondence $\Bbb N\to\{6^{n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\}:n\mapsto 6^{n+1}$.

Comment: Please have a look at the edited question. I have provided the definition for a set to be infinite.

Comment: @Y.X. : I have added some explanation. Is it clear now?

Answer (score -1):

If i understand your question correctly, your set is defined as :

$S = n \in \mathbb N | n \ne p^q$ for any prime $p$ and positive integers $q$

It is sufficient to prove that a subset of $S$ is infinite.

Consider the subset $P = n!, n \in \mathbb N, n\ge 3$ clearly, it satisfies your condition that they are not the powers of a single prime.

Now suppose we have a set $T = [1,2,....,n]$ such that $P(T) = n$ for some natural n. ($P(T)$ denotes the cardinality of set $ T$). For there to exist a bijection $f: P \to T, P(T) = P(P)$. But clearly, $(n+4)! \in P$. Which means that the cardinality of $P$ is at least $(n+4) -3 =n+1$. Thus there cannot exist any bijection,for any natural $n$. Thus, $P$ is an infinite set. Since, $P \subset S$, $S$ is also infinite.

I just made the proof up right now. If there are anu fatal errors,please point it out. I will remove/edit the answer likewise.